# Is there a way to append a div to already existing div generated automatically by leaflet in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, leaflet

Please, read the question two times, this is not a duplicate.

Is it possible to append a div generated by me in JSX to a div automatically generated by leaflet library in React?

```
<div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left">
```

Leaflet library automatically creates es div where it stores layers, etc ...
I have created my own layer selector and I would like to append it to the div in order to have it with correct alignment. I want to add it to the div beacuse I have mixed layers one is created by leaflet and the other is created by me.

Now I am just positioning my custom layer near the leaflet div, but with different screen ratio/sizes it tends to be not aligned.

Here's is the problem, it is not properly aligned sometimes:

[image: Here's is the problem, it is not properly aligned sometimes]

Is there something like :

```
DOM.writeByClassApend("leaflet-top leaflet-left", MyCustomLayer()}
```

Or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think it would not be a duplicate?

Comment: Because, in react js the typical response for this type of question is use the react hrefs to locate elements, but it in this case the div is generated automatically by leaflet so I can't reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Is it possible to add a custom div to an already existing div generated by leaflet in React?

Yes, it is possible by using this library [react-leaflet-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-control)

### Solution

Inside your map include this component ***Control*** specifying your the position you want, and inside this component specify your custom ***Component***

```
import Control from 'react-leaflet-control';

    <Map
      center={this.state.center}
      zoom={10}
    >
      <Control position="topleft" >
        <div>
           My custom div
        </div>
      </Control>

      <TileLayer
        url='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        attribution='© <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        maxZoom={18}
      />
      



    </Map>
```